# Nodemailer Error: Missing credentials for "LOGIN"

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer, mailer

I tried to add nodemailer to my node js project but it shows **Error:  Missing credentials for "LOGIN"**

**This  is my code:**

````
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "hotmail",
  auth: {
    usre: "abcd@outlook.com",
    pass: "abcd",
  },
});
const options = {
  from: "abcd@outlook.com",
  to: "md.mygmail@gmail.com",
  subject: "sending email form nodemailer",
  text: "This is nodemailer bot",
};

transporter.sendMail(options, function (err, info) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("sent: " + info.response);
});```
````

Comment: Is it a typo? You have `auth.usre` instead of `auth.user`

Comment: Does your outlook account have two-step verification enabled? If so, you'll need to use an app specific password. 

Instructions for creating an app specific password can be found here - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944

Comment: make sure that you import credentials correctly in a case you are using .env